# Docker run -d <private image> gives fatal. On other hosts it's ok?

Tags: docker

Let the commands speak for themselves:

on a host called: **coreworker**

```
core@coreworker-1 ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
hub-docker-repo:5000/485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059                            1                   bbd5d4d98156        31 minutes ago      139.3 MB
ec2-54-169-239-164.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/hub-action-repository   latest              66ecb895d185        14 hours ago        856.4 MB
ec2-54-169-239-164.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/hub-ext-node-base       0.12.7              f2f1afc202e4        8 days ago          136.6 MB
...

core@coreworker-1 ~ $
```

on a host called **devhost**

```
core@devhost ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>                       <none>              67e45ce93dee        48 minutes ago      725 MB
node                         0.12.7              a4b45afffe4a        5 days ago          642.2 MB
jwnintex/mesos-worker        latest              42f1b41b0089        5 weeks ago         504 MB
jwnintex/nginx-port-router   latest              11edcdf1a5fc        9 weeks ago         126.4 MB
jwnintex/consul              latest              e66fb6787628        10 weeks ago        69.4 MB
jwnintex/mesos-master        latest              187d84106a3e        3 months ago        561.8 MB
jwnintex/marathon            latest              b1d8dd91146a        3 months ago        699.3 MB
jwnintex/zookeeper           latest              9b72d56707c9        4 months ago        304.3 MB
jwnintex/registrator         latest              b1c29d1a74a9        6 months ago        11.79 MB
```

but when I do:

```
core@devhost ~ $ docker images -a hub-docker-repo:5000
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
```

now run the image on **devhost** residing in **hub-docker-repo**

veryify it's up:

```
core@devhost ~ $ ping hub-docker-repo
PING hub-docker-repo.service.consul (172.17.8.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from coreworker-1.node.dc1.consul (172.17.8.150): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=8.27 ms
64 bytes from coreworker-1.node.dc1.consul (172.17.8.150): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=5.19 ms
```

now try it

```
core@devhost ~ $ docker run -d hub-docker-repo:5000/485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059:1
Unable to find image 'hub-docker-repo:5000/485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059:1' locally
Pulling repository hub-docker-repo:5000/485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059
FATA[0000] Error: image 485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059:1 not found
```

Now try it on **coreworker** which is actually hosting the registry (as a docker image)

```
core@coreworker-1 ~ $ docker run -d hub-docker-repo:5000/485d5874-c786-4b90-93ac-8db5342a6059:1
98d642c1bafd30569d853e92167c7b4fe720bd67f65ec0d0719ec5a36bb6616f
```

Why am I not able to run that remote image? Or better, even discover it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the image had never been pushed and so couldn't be seen by the other host.